# Issues With namespace reference. C# 'Reporting'

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, namespaces

I am doing some maintenance on an application that was developed by a different developer that i can no longer contact.

The project was build in Visual Studios 2008 and I only have 2010 now. After doing the “upgrade  wizard”. I get two warnings and a ton of errors that I am not sure how to solve.

> The referenced component 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms' could not be found.
>   The referenced component 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common' could not be found.

If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great. I have had a rough time finding a solution on goggle.

Note: This is a stand-alone application not a web app.

Comment: Check the references, you'll have one with a yellow ! symbol. You'll need to delete it, and then re-add the reference assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Path of reference has changed, search assembly in .Net version framework, and add reference

Add reference and browse to this directory : %programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\ReportViewer\

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem here, but i fixed my problem by install MICROSOFT® REPORT VIEWER RUNTIME from Package Manager Consol.

From visual studio choose Tools -> Libraty Package Console -> Package Manager Console. Then Type: PM >Install-Package Microsoft.ReportViewer.
and my problem is gone